# The product of an arbitrary family of locally convex spaces is locally convex.

Tags: general-topology, topological-vector-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

> Let $\{E_\alpha\ : \ \alpha\in I\}$ be a family of a locally convex sets, where $I$ is an index family. I want to prove that
> $$E:= \prod_{\alpha\in I}E_\alpha$$
> is locally convex.

I know that, by definition, for each $\alpha\in I$, $E_\alpha$ is locally convex, that is, $E_\alpha$ is topological vector space such that there is a basis of neighborhoods in $E_\alpha$ consisting of convex sets. I also know that I must prove that there is a basis of neighborhoods in $E$ formed by convex sets, but I do not know how to prove it from hypotheses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $C$ be a collection of convex spaces.
Let $a = \prod_{s \in C}a_s$
and $b = \prod_{s \in C}b_s$
be two points in $\prod C$.
Show that the line from $a$ to $b$ is within $\prod C$.

Comment: What is $a_s$? What means $s \in C$?

Comment: @GuilhermedeLoreno $a_s$ is a point in s, one of the convex spaces of the collection C of convex spaces.

Answer (score 4):

$E$ has a base from the product topology, i.e. every open subset is a union of basic open sets which are of the form $\prod_{\alpha \in I} O_\alpha$ where all $O_\alpha \subseteq E_\alpha$ are open and there is a finite set $F$ of indices such that $O_\alpha = E_\alpha$ for all $\alpha \notin F$.

Now show that this remains a base if we take all non-trivial $O_\alpha$ to be convex open as well, and that the resulting basic open set is then also convex.